# Objective C: NSRange or similar with float?

Tags: objective-c, typedef, nsrange

For some methods I want them to return a range of values (from: 235, to: 245). I did this using `NSRange` as a return value

```
- (NSRange)giveMeARangeForMyParameter:(NSString *)myParameter;
```

This works fine as long as the return value is an `integer` range (e.g. location: 235, length: 10).

But now I have the problem that I need to return a `float` range (e.g. location: 500.5, length: 0.4). I read in the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) that `NSRange` is a typedefed struct with `NSUIntegers`. Is it possible to typedef another struct for `float` ranges? And if so, can there be a similar method to `NSMakeRange(NSUInteger loc, NSUInteger len)` to create those `float` ranges?

Comment: Use NSPoint (message too short).

Comment: 1. Yes, it is possible. 2. Yes, there can be.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: `NSPoint` is not unhandy when it gets to multiple platforms (iOS doesn't know `NSPoint`)...

Comment: @FrankZp I thought you were on OS X. Use CGPoint then.

Comment: Using `CGPoint` is a leaky abstraction, imo. Will confuse other code readers. Making your own struct seems better here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you could reuse one of several "pair objects" from the graphics library (you can pick from a `CGPoint` or `CGSize`, or their `NS...` equivalents) the `struct`s behind these objects are so simple that it would be better to create your own:

```
typedef struct FPRange {
    float location;
    float length;
} FPRange;

FPRange FPRangeMake(float _location, float _length) {
    FPRange res;
    res.location = _location;
    res.length = _length;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed very simple. Regarding multi-platform development this solution is better than using pair objects from graphics library (Mac OS and iOS have different objects...)

Comment: Naming the method `FPRangeMake` would be better. I know there is `NSMakeRange` but that's unique between `CGPointMake`, `CGSizeMake` and similar functions.

Comment: @Sulthan You're right, I've been out of Objective C for some months now, so I started forgetting the naming conventions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can even go and look at the definitions of `NSRange` and `NSMakeRange` (in `NSRange.h`, easiest way to get there is to 'command click' on `NSRange` name in Xcode) to see how to do it:

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
    NSUInteger location;
    NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;

NS_INLINE NSRange NSMakeRange(NSUInteger loc, NSUInteger len) {
    NSRange r;
    r.location = loc;
    r.length = len;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why it's `_NSRange` instead of just `NSRange` in the `typedef struct`?

Comment: @JonathanLin just the naming convention used by Apple (for internal / private things)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an existing struct with 2 floats and you don't mind including GLKit, you could use GLKVector2.  It also has a Make function.

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of the IOS 9 SDK, a new structure has been added by Apple which best match the OP subject:

```
UIFloatRange UIFloatRangeMake(CGFloat minimum, CGFloat maximum); // The range of motion for attached objects.
```

There are couple of useful helper functions to compare ranges too:

```
BOOL UIFloatRangeIsInfinite(UIFloatRange range);
BOOL UIFloatRangeIsEqualToRange(UIFloatRange range, UIFloatRange otherRange);
```